# Javascript object method returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, function, geolocation, undefined

Here is a quick question, I have the following method within an object, why is it returning undefined?

```
var getGeoLocation = function() {
            if (typeof(navigator.geolocation) != 'undefined') {
                var test = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
                    var lng = position.coords.longitude;
                    return(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));    
                });
            }
        }
var testFunction = function() {alert(getGeoLocation()); // returns undefined?}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because [`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_geolocation#Getting_the_current_position) is asynchronous. The `getGeoLocation` function returns before the anonymous callback function passed to `getCurrentPosition` has been executed, and since the `getGeoLocation` function has no `return` statement, it returns `undefined`.

Move code that depends on the response from `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` inside the callback.

Answer (score 2):

It returns undefined because getGeoLocation does not return anything. Try this instead:

```
var getGeoLocation = function() {
            if (typeof(navigator.geolocation) != 'undefined') {
                var test = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
                    var lng = position.coords.longitude;
                    alert(new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng));    
                });
            }
        }
var testFunction = function() {getGeoLocation()};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function GetCurrentLocation()
            {
                if (navigator.geolocation) { 
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {  

                                                             var point = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, 
                                                                                                position.coords.longitude);
alert(point);
                } 
                else {
                    alert('W3C Geolocation API is not available');
                }
            }
```

Use this code. It will give you the perfect result.